# SVG scale transformation different in IE using Velocity.js

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, transform, velocity.js

I am animating an SVG and am using scale as one of my transformations. In all browsers except IE it looks perfect, In IE it scales much bigger and in IE9 the scale transformation looks choppy. Any insight would be helpful as I am new to SVGs and velocity.js
Here is a link to my codepen
`enter code here`http://codepen.io/jessiemele/pen/RabjXp